# Overriding styles in material-ui with JSS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have html structure like this.

[image]

And 2 components

**HeaderNavItem.jsx**

```
const HeaderNavItem = ({ classes, className, children }) => (
  <div className={cn(classes.root, className)}>{children}</div>
);

export default withStyles({
  root: {
    '&:$NavLink': {
      background: 'red',
    },
  },
})(HeaderNavItem);
```

**NavLink.jsx**

```
const NavLink = ({
  exact, to, children, className, classes, onClick,
}) => (
  <RRNavLink to={to} exact={exact} className={cn(classes.root, className)} onClick={onClick}>
    {children}
  </RRNavLink>
);

export default withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    background: 'blue',
  },
}))(NavLink);
```

But the background is still blue. I get a warning in the browser console:

> Warning: [JSS] Could not find the referenced rule NavLink in HeaderNavItem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$ref` syntax is for referencing an other rule, not component. See sample code [here](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/652)

Comment: ok, how do I fix my code?

Comment: Try '&:a' or something like that